# How to load another component in the same place angular 5?

Tags: angular

All I want is when I click on Consult it shows a form with the details of the user instead of the table, and when I click delete the line will be deleted from without refresh if it's possible , what I should do for both cases ? Thanks

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skpIP.png)

Comment: you can show a modal when clicking consult, for the delete, you can just remove it from the array where you use ngFor

Comment: Showing between the "user details" and "table" can be handle via your routing, nothing special there. Deleting without refresh can be done just by deleting it from the array as mentioned by Aivan, if you are using server side you will have to fetch a fresh data from the server.

Comment: you can see angular hero sample [how to delete it from the array](https://stackblitz.com/angular/xkyalvboyrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this,
in ts:

```
userList: Array<User> = new Array<User>();
userList.push(user)
...

onDelete(index){
    this.userList.splice(index, 1);
}
```

in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userList; let i = index">
    <h2>{{ user.name }}</h2>
    <button (click)="onDelete(i)">delete</button>
</div>
```